Float values get rounded creating a Hex Grid in Unity
My code generates a grid with a specified width and height and Instantiates a "hexTilePrefab" at the calculated floating point positions. The prefab has a class "HexTile" attached to it. Within HexTile "TileCoordinates" is defined as:
public Vector2 TileCoordinates { get; set; }
As seen in the comments of my code, assigning the directly by using a new Vector2() rounds the coordinates. As an example view image 2, where the coordinates are x=0.5 and y=0.86, but the code produces x=1 and y=1. Only if I assign the x and y values separately to a vector and then assign that vector to the coordinates, they are not rounded and are correctly established.

I would like to understand why this is the case, as I don't see how a Vector2 would automatically round any values. Thanks in advance!
I used the Console to keep track of the xPos and yPos values at all times and they always seemed to be correct. But right after tile.TileCoordinates = new Vector2(xPos, yPos); would be called and I would print out the TileCoordinates, they would suddenly be rounded.
I also asked ChatGPT 4o and didn't really get any further (to no surprise) :-)
Here is the code as text:
void GenerateBoard()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            float xPos = x * tileOffsetX + (y % 2 == 0 ? 0 : tileOffsetX / 2);
            float yPos = y * tileOffsetY;
            
            GameObject hexTile = Instantiate(hexTilePrefab, new Vector2(xPos, yPos), Quaternion.identity);
            
            HexTile tile = hexTile.GetComponent<HexTile>();
            
            // xPos e.g. = 0.5 
            // yPos e.g. = 0.86
            
            // works, coordinates are not rounded
            var vector2 = tile.TileCoordinates;
            vector2.x = xPos;
            vector2.y = yPos;
            tile.TileCoordinates = vector2; 
            //-->                               tile.TileCoordinates = (0.5, 0.86)
            
            // doesn't work, coordinates are rounded
            tile.TileCoordinates = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
            
            //-->                               tile.TileCoordinates = (1, 1)
            
            /*
                why???
                TileCoordinates is a Vector2, xPos and yPos are floats
                in HexTile defined as:
                public Vector2 TileCoordinates { get; set; }
            */                
        }
    }
}


Is HexTile your implementation? can we see it? maybe TileCoordinates is a property and indeed applies some magic? From here e.g. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Hexagonal.html they indeed use int based coordinates ...

Vector2 values do not round values. ToString of Vector2 does by default round to 2 decimal places, but this is only when printing them out. The actual values are not affected.
Note that 0.86 is not the correct value for a hexagon. It should be sin(60) or sqrt(3f/4f) which is more like 0.8660254...
Your two code snippets will result in the same value. It doesn't matter how you construct the Vector2 value. In the end it's just a struct / value type. The Vector2 constructor is literally just this.
public Vector2(float x, float y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


That explanation makes sense to me even though it's quite frustrating. The actual values stay the same but printing them out rounds them, making it look like the values magically rounded up. Thank-you.
However, since I tried printing out both implementations and only one of them was rounded printing it out, I still wonder why that happens with only one of the two implementations?
